# RequireJS Text Plugin installed with Bower

Tags: configuration, requirejs, bower

How should I be using `requirejs-text` which is installed via bower? I am supposed to put it in `baseUrl` but wonder if I could use it from `components/requirejs-text/`? Whats the best practice?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Define the path to the plugin in the config:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "text" : "components/requirejs-text/text"
    }
},
```

And use it in your module as documented on https://github.com/requirejs/text:

```
require(["some/module", "text!some/module.html", "text!some/module.css"],
    function(module, html, css) {
        //the html variable will be the text
        //of the some/module.html file
        //the css variable will be the text
        //of the some/module.css file.
    }
);
```

You can use also technically use the plugin without the path definition in the requirejs.config, but this is propbably not best practice:

```
require(["your_path_to_the_plugin_from_baseurl/without_js_at_the_end!some/textfile"],
    function(yourTextfile) {
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

in `PROJECT_APP/bower.js` add this line under the dependencies section:

```
"requirejs": "~2.1.8",
"requirejs-text":"~2.0.10", // this is new
"qunit": "~1.12.0",
```

then run `bower install`, it should install this plugin and display at the end a path such as `requirejs-text#2.0.10 vendor/bower/requirejs-text` (depends on your configuration).

Finally, in the config.js file, add this line under

```
require.config({
    paths: {

        // Make vendor easier to access.
        "vendor": "../vendor",
        // Almond is used to lighten the output filesize.
        "almond": "../vendor/bower/almond/almond",

         // add the requirejs text plugin here 
         "text" : "../vendor/bower/requirejs-text/text",

        // Opt for Lo-Dash Underscore compatibility build over Underscore.
        "underscore": "../vendor/bower/lodash/dist/lodash.underscore",

        // Map remaining vendor dependencies.
        "jquery": "../vendor/bower/jquery/jquery",
        "backbone": "../vendor/bower/backbone/backbone"
    }

});
```

Then to use it, simply require it, in this case you can access it with the `template` variable

```
define([
    // These are path alias that we configured in our bootstrap
    'app',        // general app variables
    'jquery',     // lib/jquery/jquery
    'underscore', // lib/underscore/underscore
    'backbone',   // lib/backbone/backbone
    'text!templates/books.html' // use the plugin to import a template
], function(app,$, _, Backbone, template){ // don't forget to define it !
```

Comment: How does `"vendor": "../vendor"` helps making vendor "easier to access"? You won't require the vendor directory in any case.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have install requirejs-text using bower

In your project's bower.json file:

```js
{
    "name":"{{YOUR PROJECT NAME}}",
    "version":"{{YOUR PROJECT VERSION}}",
    "dependencies":{
        "requirejs-text":"2.0.6"
     }
}
```

Comment: I meant to ask how do I configure requireJS to use the text plugin. I understand its meant to be put in app's `baseUrl`, but since its in bower `components`, how do I use it?

Comment: bower only helps you to pull all the files (yes the whole github) to your local environment. You may still need to configure another tool to extract it even further more. One example of such tool is [grunt-bower-task](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task). After that, configure the text plugin in requirejs.config as usual.

Comment: Other than text plugin, you may also want to consider requirejs-tpl plugin https://github.com/jfparadis/requirejs-tpl which is more convienient to use

Comment: doesn't answer the right question of *how to use*, but *how to install* it

Comment: Well, the name isn't really `requirejs-text` with version 2.0.10.